# Animating css's after and before selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to animate CSS's selectors :before and :after in jQuery's .animate() function? If not, what is the best alternative to doing that?

Comment: @Jai He explicitly asked *if* it were possible.

Comment: **If not, what is the best alternative to doing that?** He also added this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short no - jQuery does not support pseudo element animations or even selectors I believe.

You can however animate pseudo elements using css3 transitions but it is to note that *only* Firefox 4.0+ supports it currently, so your playing field is very limited.

If it's that important, just create new child elements in the element you want to animate them.

## Update

Pseudo element animations/transitions [are now supported in Chrome](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632) as of January 1st, 2013.

You can find a browser support table [here](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/).

Comment: +1 for the news that Firefox supports pseudo-element animation/transition; I was firmly under the belief (due to Chromium's lack of support) that such was (currently) impossible.