# Why :after and :before aren't resizing on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hover over my div(#hotspot) the ribbons(.rtc and .rbc) change their scale and position,but the main ribbons(.rtc:after and .rtc:before,.rbc:after and .rbc:before) just disappear and appear again, why they just dissaper and appear when the effect is active and 
why they not change their size at same time when the .rtc and .rbc classes change theirs ?
Is there any solution/fix for this.
Please answer!

```
function hsmouseenter() {
    $("#hotspot, #center").css({
        'width': '60%',
        'height': '90%',
        'top': '5%',
        'left': '20%'
    });
    $("#center").css({
        'box-shadow': '0 0 2vw white'
    });
    $(".rt, .rtc").stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '66%',
        height: '13%',
        top: '10%',
        left: '17%',
        opacity: 0
    }, 300);
    $(".rb, .rbc").stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '66%',
        height: '13%',
        bottom: '10%',
        left: '17%',
        opacity: 0
    }, 300)
}

function hsmouseleave() {
    $("#hotspot, #center").css({
        'width': '50%',
        'height': '80%',
        'top': '10%',
        'left': '25%'
    });
    $("#center").css({
        'box-shadow': '0 0 1vw white'
    });
    $(".rt, .rtc").stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '56%',
        height: '8%',
        top: '15%',
        left: '22%',
        opacity: 1
    }, 400)
    $(".rb, .rbc").stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '56%',
        height: '8%',
        bottom: '15%',
        left: '22%',
        opacity: 1
    }, 400)
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ultraga/3m2UA/1/

Comment: You should be able to do all of this with pure CSS transitions.

Comment: no,because my jquery needs to change css at some moments instead of hover!

Comment: Then add and remove a class, and use CSS transitions.

Comment: men forget that it still wont fix the :after and :before elements to scale like their parents, if you can post a JSFiddle with result/fix.

Comment: @Ultraga what Blazemonger suggested you is correct, the only solution is by using transition and instead of using `animate()` method, you just need to use `css` method to change the style properties, check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/3m2UA/3/ It works better as you expected, just tweak it more yourself.

Comment: Ahaa, now I see you mean to use css instead of animate, sorry I thought you mean I should do it only with css without jquery, thank you very much 'Blazemonger' and 'King Kong' this worked, 'King Kong' if you can post your comment as an Answer with the 'JSFiddle' and I will mark it as the Right Answer! :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda impossible, lathough FF can handle it according to this posts comment: [Animating css's after and before selectors in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109964/animating-csss-after-and-before-selectors-in-jquery)

I think, You could do it using css transitions. When You cannot use hover You can just add some class (f.e. .hover)

changed in Your example

```
overflow:visible !important;
```

and opacity to 1 to make You see pseudo elements are showing after animation.
http://jsfiddle.net/3SHFJ/